# Set Docker_Opts in centos

Tags: centos, docker

I need to set docker to listen to tcp://0.0.0.0/4243 on my host machine running amazon linux (centos). All the documentation I have seen has told me to run the following command

```
echo DOCKER_OPTS="-H=tcp://127.0.0.1:4243" >> /etc/default/docker
```

Which will write the correct docker_opts to /etc/default/docker. I've done this, but when I restart docker it does not listen to 127.0.0.1

I can make docker run correctly by typing

```
sudo /usr/bin/docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -d &
```

That works, but I want the default option to be listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 without having to specify it every time.

It seems that docker is completely ignoring my /etc/default/docker file so the settings are being ignored. I also tried writing the file to /etc/default/docker.io and /etc/default/docker-io (didn't really expect much to happen)

I need to be able to start docker with just

```
service docker start
```

or it will cause issues in my current deployment playbook.

Any thoughts on what I can do to set DOCKER_OPTS and not have to do it every time I restart docker?

Comment: How are you checking that the docker daemon does not listen on 4243?

Comment: I'm using jenkins to connect to my docker host. When I start with sudo /usr/bin/docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -d & jenkins connects with no problems. When I rely on the /ect/default/docker it fails to connect because docker is not listening on 4243.

Comment: Is Jenkins running on another host?

Comment: Yes it is, but jenkins is not the cause of the issue here. Jenkins can connect to the docker host without any issues and works fine with spawning containers. The problem is that I cannot set docker to use tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 by default.

Comment: Could you post the output of: `netstat -ant | grep 4243` after you configure /etc/default/docker and restart the service again?

Comment: There is no output, but when I use sudo /usr/bin/docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -d & I get "tcp        0      0 :::4243                     :::*                        LISTEN"

Comment: What version of docker?

Comment: With current versions of docker as of this writing, this is the suggested way. https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/reference/commandline/daemon/#daemon-configuration-file
I tried other techniques and had issues; the daemon.json file worked.  `graph` is the attribute name.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In RHEL7, instead of modifying your docker.service unit file, you can also just edit your /etc/sysconfig/docker file:

```
# /etc/sysconfig/docker

# Modify these options if you want to change the way the docker daemon runs
OPTIONS=--selinux-enabled -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243
```

and then restart your docker service.

To me, this is more reliable than modifying the service script.

Comment: Hi, the RHEL 7 / CentOS 7 docker package (1.6.2+) does not seem to use "fd://" any more. My version is CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)

Comment: This line seems to work instead: OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243'

Comment: Yes, you're right (but it was correct at the time I wrote the post, i.e. with docker 1.2). I have fixed my post.

Comment: This does not seem to be a valid answer any longer

Comment: FYI this also works for the latest (and final) version of Docker for CentOS 6

Answer (score 18):

For CentOS 7 (RHEL 7):

Find the systemd docker.service unit file. Mine is located at: `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`

In this file, edit the line in the [Service] section beginning with `ExecStart=`. Add the "`-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243`" into the line. (notice there's no "=" between the -H and the IP address as in your example DOCKER_OPTS line above.)

On my system, the entire contents of `docker.service` then looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=http://docs.docker.com
After=network.target docker.socket
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker -d -H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 -H fd:// $OPTIONS
LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576

[Install]
Also=docker.socket
```

(I only need Docker to listen on the loopback, instead of all IP addresses.)

After making this edit to the systemd unit file and restarting the Docker service via `systemctl restart docker`, I see the following process:

`root      8574  0.0  0.2 321708 10564 ?        Ssl  00:42   0:00 /usr/bin/docker -d -H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243 -H fd:// --selinux-enabled`

As you can see, it does now listen on the configured TCP address, and will persist over reboots and service stop/starts.

Comment: what is the fd://  means ?

Comment: I dont have the docker.socket file

Comment: docker.service can be found in the following way: systemctl show --property=FragmentPath docker

Comment: See my latest answer as I believe things have changed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44834532/1258525

Answer (score 12):

I cannot believe how many answers there are for this. So here is another one for:

- CentOS 7.3
- Docker Version = 17.03.1-ce, API Version = 1.27

This answer is built upon an unbelievable playing around combination of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26396546/1258525) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33277025/1258525) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35224712/1258525).

1. sudo vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
2. insert " -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
   [image]
3. sudo systemctl daemon-reload //refresh your file changes above
4. sudo systemctl restart docker
5. netstat -l | grep 4243 //verify port is open
6. connect to your docker host from somewhere, like Jenkins Docker Plugin, i.e. tcp://[server_ip]:4243

Comment: Specifically for Docker 17.03.ce, this is the only answer that worked for me on CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core); daemon.json didnt work; there was no sysconfig file; setting OPTIONS did not help. The installation was done following https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#install-docker-ce-1. Also you have to install docker using this cmd: ```sudo yum install --setopt=obsoletes=0 docker-ce-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64 docker-ce-selinux-17.03.2.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch```

Answer (score 4):

Editing [`/etc/docker/daemon.json`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/#configure-the-docker-daemon) seems to be the new, supported way.

Comment: Checkout [Specify DNS servers for Docker](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#specify-dns-servers-for-docker)

Answer (score 3):

With Docker 1.7.1 on CentOS 7 neither modifying `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service` or `/etc/sysconfig/docker` worked for me. It seems that in systemd sets up the socket, so in order to change the group you have to edit SocketGroup in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.socket`

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Socket for the API
PartOf=docker.service

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=root
SocketGroup=jenkins

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Answer (score 2):

I Think on CentOS, you can try setting the options as below in the file **/etc/sysconfig/docker**

```
other_args="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

Then restart the docker and try checking if the port is opening using

```
netstat -plt | grep 4243
```

This should list if listening

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change the default bridge interface docker0 to use my own bridge interface br0 and putting the following content in that file solved my issue:

CentOS 7.2 and docker 1.10.3

/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf

```
[Service] 
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon --bridge=br0 -H fd://
```

and of course the following need to be performed after:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl restart docker 

ip link del docker0
```

Comment: Can you tell why you created your own bridge instead of the docker one?

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I followed how its shown in the posts above with drop-in replacement files in: `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`

Answer (score 0):

I am working on centos 7.

I just want to add insecure-registry in docker config file then I changed "DOCKER_OPTS=--insecure-registry=...." in /etc/sysconfig/docker while it did not work.

While I saw a INSECURE_REGISTRY in the config so I changed this variable and it WORKS!

So I guess DOCKER_OPTS does not work here!

But it worked on my unbuntu 14!

It is really frustrating when using docker!

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/configuring/

`sudo mkdir /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`
`sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf`

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon -H fd:// -D -H tcp://127.0.0.1:4243
```

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
`sudo systemctl restart docker`

Answer (score 0):

1、edit /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service to add two param in the service section:

```
# vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

[Service]

ExecStart=

ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix://var/run/docker.sock

2、reload the configuration,and then restart docker。

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl restart docker
```

3、to check for success, see if the return the following response。

```
# ps -ef|grep docker
```

root     26208     1  0 23:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix://var/run/docker.sock

reference from [Expose the Docker Remote API on Centos 7?](https://forums.docker.com/t/expose-the-docker-remote-api-on-centos-7/26022/2)

Answer (score 0):

I believe things have changed now, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44834532/3438276) answer by Brian Ogden had worked for me earlier but didn't work on my environment today, probably with the updated versions of the docker, kernel, and OS.

```
CentOS 7.4.1708 (on AWS)
Docker 17.03.2-ce
API 1.27
```

This is what worked after few hit and trials. I could not find it documented anywhere.

In file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/execstart.conf`, replace the last `ExecStart` (there are two) with below

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --graph=/var/lib/docker --storage-driver=overlay -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

Now, my files looks like this

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/execstart.conf
[Service]
Restart=always
StartLimitInterval=0
RestartSec=15
ExecStartPre=-/sbin/ip link del docker0
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --graph=/var/lib/docker --storage-driver=overlay -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
#
```

Once, the above file is changed just the run the below command to activate the changes.

```
# systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl stop docker && rm -f /var/run/docker.sock && systemctl start docker
```

To verify if everything is working fine, you can run any (or all) of below commands

```
# systemctl status docker.service | grep tcp
           ├─21812 /usr/bin/dockerd --graph=/var/lib/docker --storage-driver=overlay -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
#
# netstat -an | grep 4243
tcp6       0      0 :::4243                 :::*                    LISTEN
#
# ps aux | grep [4]243
root     21812  1.0  0.8 1017512 67876 ?       Ssl  15:11   0:06 /usr/bin/dockerd --graph=/var/lib/docker --storage-driver=overlay -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
#
# docker -H :4243 info
```