# How do i expose the Docker Remote API on Centos 7?

Tags: docker, centos7, docker-api

On ubuntu i can go into `/etc/init/docker.conf` and put in `DOCKER_OPTS='-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock'` to get the json data to display on my browser but how can i do it for Centos?

I have tried creating a file in `/etc/sysconfig/docker` and placing `other_args="-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"` inside the file and restarting docker but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: From where did you install the docker package?  The one in CentOS (docker-1.10.3-46.el7.centos.14.x86_64) reads `/etc/sysconfig/docker`.  The one from Docker corp. (docker-engine-1.12.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64) does not.

Comment: @larsks i installed it from docker corp (1.12.2) is there any way i can expose the port on centos with docker 1.12.2? I need 1.12+ due to its swarm mode

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The systemd unit installed by the Docker corp package hardcodes the command line used to start the docker daemon:

```
[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
[...]
```

There is no support for reading a file from `/etc/sysconfig` or elsewhere to modify the command line.  Fortunately, systemd gives us the tools we need to change this behavior.

The simplest solution is probably to create the file `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker-external.conf` (the exact filename doesn't matter; it just needs to end with `.conf`) with the following contents:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

And then:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart docker
```

This is actually documented on the Docker website in [this document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/), which includes instructions for a more flexible solution that will allow you to use files in `/etc/sysconfig` to control the daemon.

Comment: On AWS CentOS 7 AMI, somehow restart did not work for me. This worked `systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl stop docker && rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock && systemctl start docker` For some weird reason, `docker.sock` was being created as a directory instead of a socket file.

Comment: There is no need to create an extra file for the same on CentOS 7. I have given my answer in another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51116208/3438276).

Comment: Your answer seems to rely on a drop-in file (`/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/execstart.conf`) just like this one.

Comment: Yeah, kind of. I have just tweaked a current file, rather than creating a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do the configuration thing.  But how about a docker solution to a docker problem?

```
docker run -d \
--name sherpa \                 
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock \
-p 2375:4550 \
djenriquez/sherpa --allow
```

Proxies access to the socket through port 2375 on localhost.

Answer (score -2):

1、edit /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service to add two params in the service section:

```
# vim /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

[Service]

ExecStart=

ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix://var/run/docker.sock

2、reload the configuration, and then restart docker。

```
# systemctl daemon-reload
# systemctl restart docker
```

3、to check for success, see if the return the following response。

```
# ps -ef|grep docker
```

root     26208     1  0 23:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 -H unix://var/run/docker.sock

reference from [Expose the Docker Remote API on Centos 7?](https://forums.docker.com/t/expose-the-docker-remote-api-on-centos-7/26022)

Comment: Don't edit `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`, because it will get replaced next time you install the `docker` package.  This is what `/etc/systemd/system` is for.